# How to Redirect to loginpage if Session variable is null from web.config file?

Tags: asp.net

I dealing with the next problem, I have  a asp.net web project in which I have a login page, depending of the user that logs in it will be redirected to a Main Menu page, When the users inserts the user and passwords in the textboxes of the login page and clicks a log in button I save the user's data into a Session variable in order to use it in the next pages,if I run the application from other page different to the login page the application will crash because there's no Session variable.
My question is if is it possible to redirect to login page from web config if the Session variable is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to checkout some of the built in ASP.NET authentication providers such as forms authentication as they come with the functionality you are looking for built in.

[Forms Authentication Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh.aspx)

With the forms authentication provider you can specify a default login page to redirect unauthenticated users to:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a master page in your solution? If so, you can store the user session in the master page, and on Page_Load in the master page, check to see if a user is logged in. If no user is logged in, redirect to the login page.

You could probably also do this by adding a Global.asax file to your solution. In the code behind for the Global.asax file, add the following event:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check yourself:

```
var valueIExpect = Session["MyKEY"] as whatevertype;

if(valueIexpect ==null)
Response.Redirect("Someplaceelse.aspx");
```

Comment: I did that in the pages that are after the loggin on page load event, my question is if is it possible to do that in web config file?

Comment: No, there's no way to store specific session values in Web.config . I don't see a problem with doing it in code yourself. It's 2,3 lines only. If you need to apply it to many pages, just extend your pages from a BasePage and overload OnPageLoad and put that line of code there